# Can I prevent a computed column from changing it's value if the formula changes?

Tags: sql-server

I have a computed column in MS SQL 2005 that does some VAT calculations. The website uses invoices that can only be generated once and rely on the value in the computed column to work out the VAT.

Unfortunately, a bug was found that means that the the VAT value calculated was off by a few cents. Not a huge problem but we can't change the values from all the previously computed values as these need to be honoured on the invoices.

tldr;
How do I change the calculation for a computed column without re-calculating the values that have already be calculated?

Comment: How are you applying the calculation/formula on the column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short, you can't, because the computed column definition applies to all rows in the table. But why are you using a computed column here anyway? If (when) the VAT rate changes, the rules for applying it to goods and services change, and the number of invoices increases over time, then a computed column becomes more and more awkward as a solution.

It would be a lot simpler and safer to calculate the VAT once, store it in a column and then just don't update the value. You can use permissions, triggers and/or auditing to ensure that the value is not changed after being entered.

So I would add a new, non-computed column, copy the values from the computed column and drop the computed column (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118/sql-server-alter-computed-column)). Plus whatever application development you need to do to actually calculate the values in the first place, of course. It's some extra work but since you've found a bug you have to fix it anyway.

Comment: Completely agree. Just what my answer was going to say.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a datestamp on the row your formula can vary based on that value.  Note that you will have to drop the computed column and re-add it.  This will require minimal integration, however I think eventually you should plan on stamping this value instead of using the calculation.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable ( low int, high int, insertdate datetime, myavg AS (low + high)/2 ) ;

insert into dbo.mytable values (1,10,'10-10-10')
insert into dbo.mytable values (1,10,'10-10-10')
insert into dbo.mytable values (2,20,'11-11-11')

alter table dbo.mytable add myavgplusone as ( case when insertdate < '11-1-11' then (low + high)/2 else ((low + high)/2)+1 end)


select * from dbo.mytable
```